# How to install node-sqlserver

Tags: installation, apt-get, aptitude

I have tried apt-get  install aptitude but i got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: libboost-iostreams1.42.0 (>= 1.42.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcwidget3 but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl but it is not going to be installed
 phpmyadmin : Depends: php5-mysql but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-mysqli but it is not installable
              Recommends: mysql-client
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f instal
```

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve it?

Comment: Probably a bit off topic for this site. What OS is this? Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Did you what apt-get suggested and performed

`root# apt-get -f install` ?

What about your /etc/apt/sources.list file? Is it up-to-date?